# Using Javascript to find the tabindex of the last entry of a list and then extract innerText from it

Tags: javascript, html, html-lists

I would like to use Javascript to extract innerText from the last entry of an html list on a web page. The list uses tabindex, so that seems like the best way of identifying the last entry. However, the list is also dynamic, so the tabindex number of the final entry will change day to day. I'm pretty new at this, but it would seem that I need the script to find the tabindex number of the last entry, and then use document.querySelector to get the innerText of that entry? Here's an example of what the list looks like:

```
<div id="container">
  <ul id=“list”>
    <li class=“entry” tabindex=“0” id=“entry0”></li>
    <li class=“entry” tabindex=“1” id=“entry1”></li>
    <li class=“entry” tabindex=“2” id=“entry2”></li>
    <li class=“entry” tabindex=“3” id=“entry3”></li>
    <li class=“entry” tabindex=“4” id=“entry4”></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I've also been reviewing some similar questions with great answers, but I've had difficulty modifying the code to do exactly what I'm looking for. This is the closest solution I've found on the site(answer provided by Elliot Frisch).

```
function moveNext(tabInput) {
  var lastTab = 3;
  var curIndex = tabInput.tabIndex;
  var tabs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  if(curIndex >= lastTab) { //if we are on the last tab then go back to the beginning
    curIndex = 0;
  }
  for(var i=0; i < tabs.length; i++) { // loop over the tabs.
    if(tabs[i].tabIndex == (curIndex+1)) { // is this our tab?
        tabbables[i].focus(); // Focus and leave.
        break;
    }
}
```

Does anybody have any ideas? I'd love to crack this nut.

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: For a start, use standard `"`, not `“”`.

Comment: Your `li` elements *have* no text...?

Comment: Do you want the `li` with the highest `tabindex`, or the *last* `li`? They aren't necessarily the same thing.

Comment: `document.querySelector("#list > li:last-child").textContent` will get you the text content of the last `li` in the `ul` if that's what you mean by "last entry".

Comment: I want to help, but I'm afraid I'm not following what you actually want. You can find the last `li` element in `<ul id="list">` like this: `document.getElementById("list").lastElementChiid` and then read its tabindex (`.tabIndex`) or text content (`.textContent`), etc.

Comment: @ScottMarcus - Beware whitespace text nodes. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks. Since you already showed the best DOM API, I switched mine up to go with `.querySelector()` to get there with CSS. ;)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder That's my cue to call it a day!

Comment: @ScottMarcus - :-) Me too. Catch you later. Always good to see you. :-)

Comment: @ScottMarcus Thanks for the suggestion! I'll try it out and see if it works with my use case.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'll try these too! Thanks! Basically what I'm trying to do is grab the text of the list's last entry(highest tabindex as you mentioned). In the past I've used document.querySelector().innerText to extract text from elements, but in this case I have the added complexity of identifying which list entry to grab(the one with the highest tabindex).

Comment: @ScottMarcus your solution worked perfectly! Thank you!!

Comment: @TCros - Glad that worked! But just, again, remember that the *last* `li` does not necessarily have the highest tabindex.